# Loop through Items returned from an API Call and save them in array variable

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a a `REST API` that when I call with `GET` for example from a browser I get a proper response like:

```
[
{"name": "jack",
 "id" : 23
},
{"name": "joe",
 "id" : 45
},
{"name": "james",
 "id" : 56
}
]
```

So now in `ADF` I add a `Web Activity` and call the same API.
**If at all possible:** I want to have those items from the response in a array variable so I can loop through them.
How do I do this?
I have created a `Set Variable activity` and connected to output of my `WebAPI` call like picture below
[image]
and my pipeline variable is called `apiCallOutput` with type of Array.

Looking in Pipeline Run, the output of the `Web APICall` is like this:

```
{
    "Response": "[
{"name": "jack",
 "id" : 23
},
{"name": "joe",
 "id" : 45
},
{"name": "james",
 "id" : 56
}
]",
    "typicalMetaData" : "stuff That Azure adds"
}
```

Comment: Your setup looks correct. What is the error/result you are receiving? Or what did you want to do after you set the array variable?

Comment: @AnupamChand I want to know be able to loop through those items ( three in my example )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a demonstration of how you can loop through items (and use its values) from the response which is returned using `Web` activity.

- The following is the data that would be returned by my sample web activity (a sample provided, there are 100 items in total). I am just retrieving  just *userId* and *title* for demonstration.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }
 ]
```

[image]

- You can directly use the `Response` in `For Each` activity. For `items` field in the for each activity, you can use the following dynamic content.

```
@json(activity('Web1').output.Response)
```

[image]

- Now you can access the item values inside the for each loop with 2 set variable activities. (provided dynamic content for your case)

```
#to get name value
@string(item().name) 

#to get id value
@string(item().id)
```

[image]

Now when you debug the pipeline, you can see that the required values will be retrieved.

- The output for `value1` set variable activity.

[image]

- The output for `value2` set variable activity.

[image]

This way you can assign the item values into variables (String type) and use them inside for each directly.

**NOTE:**

You can directly use the values of an item as `@item().name` and `@item().id` without using set variable activity activity as well.

Comment: Thanks, will try to follow your step. Is there a reason images are not loading ? or maybe just my work network is filtering them ...

Comment: I rechecked and the images are loading fine. Kindly try reloading or check your network.